# Add padding within an input text field to prevent overlapping

Tags: html, css

So i currently have the following bit of code:

Trouble I am having is the value I type overlaps the percentage sign. Im not sure how to go about adding some padding or alignment to **prevent the overlap**.

Any ideas?

```css
.percentBlock {
    width: 1500px;
}

.percentageSign {
    position: relative;
    right:20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="percentBlock">
    <input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" style="text-align:right;">
<span class="percentageSign">%</span></span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following solution, so the `%` is placed after the number controls:

```css
.percentBlock {
  width: 1500px;
}
.percentBlock input[type=number] {
  padding-right:20px;
}
.percentageSign {
  position: relative;
  right:20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="percentBlock">
  <input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" style="text-align:right;">
  <span class="percentageSign">%</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I would go with this solution mub33n.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this also

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.percentBlock {
 width: 200px;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
}
.percentageSign {
 position: absolute;
 right: 30px;
    top:1px;
}
.percentBlock input {
 padding-left:70.5%;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="percentBlock">
 <input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0">
<span class="percentageSign">%</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.percentBlock {
  width: 1500px;
 }
 .percentBlock input {
  text-align:left;
  width:55px;
 }
 .percentageSign {
 position: relative;
    right:35px;
}
```

```html
<span class="percentBlock">
 <input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0">
<span class="percentageSign">%</span></span>
```

I think this is what you are looking for.